# Deserializing Generic that implements Interface with a List<T> of Interfaces .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, xml-deserialization

### Scenario

I have some XML come down from a service that I want to deserialize.

Depending on what is returned from the service, the XML can vary slightly (with the element names); but the XML always follows a common structure.

Here is a sample of what the XML might look like:

```
<ATemplate>
    <Name>SomeTemplate</Name>
    <TemplateItems>
        <ATemplateItem>
            <Name>SomeTemplateItem</Name>
            <TemplateFields>
                <ATemplateField>
                    <Name>SomeTemplateField</Name>
                    <Colour>Blue</Colour>
                </ATemplateField>
                ... more template fields
            </TemplateFields>
        </ATemplateItem>
        ... more template items
    </TemplateItems>
</ATemplate>
```

Using the above XML as an example, I have created a `ATemplate` class that will deserialize nicely from the XML, using the `ATemplateItem` and `ATemplateField` classes accordingly:

```
public class ATemplate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ATemplateItem> TemplateItems { get; set; }
}

public class ATemplateItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ATemplateField> TemplateFields { get; set; }
}

public class ATemplateField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
}
```

I use this code to deserialize:

```
ATemplate template;
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
{
    template = (ATemplate)new XmlSerializer(typeof(ATemplate)).Deserialize(reader);
}
```

All good, so far.

---

### Curveball

The same scenario might occur where the XML contains `BTemplate`, `BTemplateItem`s and `BTemplateField`s; still following the structure as above.

So I created other classes for this situation:

```
public class BTemplate { ... }
public class BTemplateItem { ... }
public class BTemplateField { ... }
```

And made the relevant classes inherit respectively from `ITemplate`, `ITemplateItem` and `ITemplateField` I created, also:

### Interfaces

```
public class ITemplate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ITemplateItem> TemplateItems { get; set; }
}

public class ITemplateItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ITemplateField> TemplateFields { get; set; }
}

public class ITemplateField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
}
```

This is so I can then create one function, which is able to loop through the `ITemplateItem`s and their `ITemplateField`s and perform some cool stuff:

```
public void Foo(ITemplate template)
{
    foreach (var item in template.TemplateItems)
    {
        // do cool stuff
        foreach (var field in item.TemplateFields)
        {
            // do more cool stuff
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Some things to note:

- In the object that contains the XML, I **know** what "type" the XML contains - given an Enum I use to identify
- I then use a `switch` statement to run different methods, depending on the said "type"

---

### Generic Method?

Now, rather than deserializing the XML differently in each of those method cases, I would like to use a Generic method to deserialize.

So I created one, like this:

```
public ITemplate DeserializeTemplate<T>(string xmlString) where T : ITemplate
{
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
    {
        return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

And call it from within the specific methods like so:

```
var template = DeserializeTemplate<ATemplate>(xmlString);
```

Then, I can use the `ITemplate` that it returns, and pass it to `Foo(ITemplate template)` to go and perform some magic and wizardry.

---

### But...

No compilation errors, as yet - however I get a RunTime error, because it cannot deserialize an Interface.

I gather this is because it's trying to then deserialize the `ITemplate`'s `TemplateItems` as `ITemplateItem`s.

### Can I do the above?

My question is:

How can I get around this issue?

- Can I use this Generic deserialize method?
- Will I need to treat each one differently in the separate methods?
- Will I need to make the Interface generic also, with the types to expect?

I'm banging my head against the desk, so I really hope you lovely SO people can help.

As always, your comments, answers and suggestions are much appreciated :)

Comment: The issue here is that you are trying to deserialize to an Interface, since an interface is only a contract and not an implementation it will never work. You need to deserialize to a solid type and then cast your result to the interface.

Comment: How does `XmlSerializer` even know about the interfaces though, if he's passing in the class type as the type parameter?

Comment: @user1620220 it has nothing to do with `ATemplate`.  This has everything to do with `List<ITemplateItem>` and `List<ITemplateField>`.  This is invalid when deserializing.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly implementing the interface? And keep the concrete child properties?

Comment: Thanks @mbrdev - I agree it's because it can't deserialize the `List<ITemplate..>`s etc.  Do you suggest that I put this deserialize method inside each case method, but for the concrete types (still inheriting from the relevant interfaces)? I guess I was just trying to keep it DRY by using one generic method

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @user1620220 - If I do this, however, the concrete classes/children won't inherit from the `ITemplate...`s, though? And then I wouldn't be able to do the foreach loop on each, I think?